# What does the path <script src="~/_content.."</script> means for path?

Tags: .net, datagrid, nuget, blazor

I'm trying to add a nuget package and the description for it asks me to add in _Host.cshtml a script:

```
<script src="~/_content/radzen.blazor.gridexportoptions/radzen-grid-export-options.js"></script>
```

(with this I'm getting a not found error)

However I don't understand that path, should I download and create that folder? (if it's worth noting, the package is: https://github.com/Inspirare-LLC/Radzen.Blazor.GridExportOptions )
and I have already added the `@using Radzen.Blazor.GridExportOptions`
however I can't figure out if it's not working for not finding these .js files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't have to do anything apart from including the Nuget Package in your `<project>.csproj`. The folder `_content` will contain some files that are embedded in `Radzen.Blazor.GridExportOptions` nuget package (it is also used by other packages).

To visualize it you can access it directly on your Web Server or try to find the static files in the nuget package directly.

Comment: my project has the package reference ` <PackageReference Include="Radzen.Blazor.GridExportOptions" Version="3.3.0" />`, however it doesn't resolve, even with `<script src="/_content/..."></script>` as you post

Comment: Can you see the files in your web server and in the nuget package?

Comment: @Baldie47 I believe you are right, another possibility would be that you didn't allow static files to be served: [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-6.0#serve-files-in-web-root).